docker mysql connection refused
Can't connect to database server
docker-compose:
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: app_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8876:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: app_db
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zastroy
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8101:3306"
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci

connection settings
I tried changing the host to app_db and just db , but then it doesn’t find the address at all

Post code as text, not as images. Questions must provide a [mcve]. 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address

You are trying to connect to port 3306, but you have 8101  in your docker file.

When docker compose runs containers, it creates a docker bridge network which it connects the containers to. On the bridge network, the containers can talk to each other using the service names as host names.
That means that your other containers can reach the database using the hostname db and port 3306.
If you want to be able to reach any of the containers from outside the bridge network, you map a port on the host to a container port. You've mapped the database container port 3306 to the host port 8101.
That means that your other containers can reach the database on db:3306 but if you want to reach it from the host machine, you have to use localhost:8101.
In your screenshot, you're using localhost:3306 which won't work. You need to use port 8101 from the host.
There's more information here.

make sure you have created a docker network first so that nginx and mysql can communicate
docker network create -d bridge app_network
when it has been created, add it to docker compose with the same network on mysql and nginx
example compose

version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: app_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8876:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - app_network
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app_network
  db:
    container_name: app_db
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zastroy
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8101:3306"
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge


Compose automatically creates a network named default and automatically attaches to it.  For almost all Compose-based applications, it's correct to have no networks: blocks in the file at all.

Can I see the logs to the application container and try testing the connection to MySQL ?
docker exec -it app bash
mysql -h db -uroot -proot
and can I see the logs?
docker logs app_db
